# Mapping values based on a column in dataframe with condition involving "rest of the values"

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Is there a way to map values to a dataframe column while giving mapping values for only some of the unique values?

For example, a sample dataframe is as under:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
0      A       I      10
1      B       I      20
2      C      II      30
3      D     III      40
4      E     III      50
5      F      II      60
6      G      IV      70
7      H       V      80
8      I      VI      90
9      J     VII     100
```

Now, if I want to create a new col (`Col4`), such that for `Col2` value I it says 'Level 1', for `Col2` value II it says 'Level 2', and for all other `Col2` value, it says 'Level 3'.

Basically, I want the following without having to write the mapping for III to VII, as my actual data has hundreds of such mapping, while I only need three levels:

```
df['Col4'] = df['Col2'].map({'I':'Level 1',
'II':'Level 2',
'III':'Level 3',
'IV':'Level 3',
'V':'Level 3',
'VI':'Level 3',
'VII':'Level 3',
})
```

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of downvoting the question without even first attempting to ask for a clarification if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming people are downvoting because this type of question has been asked many times. Try searching for `np.where` or `np.select` functions.

```
import numpy as np

df['Col4'] = np.where(
    df['Col2'] == 'I','Level 1',
    np.where(
        df['Col2'] == 'II','Level 2',
        'Level 3'))
```

Prints:

```
df
Out[142]: 
  Col1 Col2  Col3     Col4
0    A    I    10  Level 1
1    B    I    20  Level 1
2    C   II    30  Level 2
3    D  III    40  Level 3
4    E  III    50  Level 3
5    F   II    60  Level 2
6    G   IV    70  Level 3
7    H    V    80  Level 3
8    I   VI    90  Level 3
9    J  VII   100  Level 3
```

Comment: I understand that the question may have been asked before. But if I am not aware of this np.where then how will I search it before asking the question. When I had asked the question, I had gone through the suggested duplicate questions and couldn't find my answer, only then I had asked this question. And what harm does a duplicate question do? They can very well just point me to the duplicate question instead of downvoting. Downvoting doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question though. This works.